# Reference to Project in Solution Showing as Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a multiple project solution and I need to reference one from the other. I've added the reference using the "Add Reference" menu but as soon as it's added it tell me that it's missing and the application will not build. However when I declare the reference in code via 'using', the intellisense does not detect any issues with the reference. Yet in the Solution explorer under the Reference folder there is a yellow triangle on the reference to indicate it's missing.

In the project file theres the following XML:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\CompanyName.Core\CompanyName.Core.csproj">
      <Project>{4ea217e8-74c2-471e-83d3-ba7dfbf776a0}</Project>
      <Name>CompanyName.Core</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompanyName.Model\CompanyName.Model.csproj">
      <Project>{33c00703-0d85-4f73-a296-b3a036bed742}</Project>
      <Name>CompanyName.Model</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The CompanyName.Model reference works fine and it's the CompanyName.Core that is apparently missing.

So far I've tried:

- Cleaning and building the solution
- Opening and Closing Visual Studio
- Removing and Re-adding the reference

Comment: which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: may be due to framework mismatching.

Comment: I've had the yellow triangle when the referenced assembly was at a higher .Net version than my project, so I'd check that the reference isn't build for a newer version of .Net.

Comment: Is the project that forms the reference actually being built? Check your build configuration to ensure that it is set to build.

Comment: might be a problem with x64 / x86 version of the dll, or it`s .net version

Comment: It was a framework mismatch @UthistranS. if you want to pop that in as the answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check the framework of the assemblies refered. 
It seems that the problem is due to framework mismatch.